# method to change shapes not working

Tags: java

The question is to get my shapes to change over time according to some criteria of my own design therefore i tried to make the shape change size as it hits certain coordinates but it would turn into line and keep moving as lines below is my move method to make my shapes move, rebound, and move horizontally and vertically.

```
public void move() {
    // Rebound X
    if (x <= 0 || x >= 400 - width) {
        moveX = moveX * -1;
    }

    // Rebound Y
    if (y <= 0 || y >= 400 - height) {
        moveY = moveY * -1;
    }

    // Wide shapes move up and down, narrow shapes move sideways
    if (width > 15) {
        y += moveY;
    } else {
        x += moveX;
    }

    // Change shape size
    if (y <= 100 || y >= 300 - height) {
        moveX = -moveX;
        height += height * 1 / 2;
    }

    //if {
    //    height -= height * 1/2;
    //    moveX = -moveX;
    //}

    //if (x < 20) {
    //    width -= width * 1/2;
    //    moveY = -moveY;
    //} else {
    //    width += width * 1/2;
    //    moveY = -moveY;
    //}
}
```

This is my shape class that all shapes extend:

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public abstract class Shape {
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected Color color;
    protected int moveX = 1;
    protected int moveY = 1;

    public Shape() {
        Random r = new Random();
        width = r.nextInt(30) + 10;
        height = width;
        x = r.nextInt(400 - width);
        y = r.nextInt(400 - height);
        color = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
    }

    // Returns random value within range (low < n <= high).
    public int randomRange(int low, int high) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        return generator.nextInt(high - low + 1) + low;
    }

    public abstract void display(Graphics page);
    public abstract void move();
}
```

Comment: (You might want to put the comments *above* the code they describe; most people read top-down.)

Comment: To the original poster: consider clarifying your question, a **lot**.

Comment: I also suggest that you use absolute values for your moves, making moveX a true negative value if x >= some number, which can prevent then number from flopping back and forth. e.g., `moveX = -Math.abs(moveX);`

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information in the code posted to see what's wrong. The only place where the `height` changes is in the line `height += height * 1/2`, and that shouldn't decrease the `height` unless it's already negative, so I can't see why you'd end up with a line.

Comment: I could send you my whole code but it is 6 support class and one main however i could edit my code to one whole support class

Comment: @M1N33 Ideally it would be reduced to the minimal amount necessary to show the problem... although it's not yet clear how the method shown, with only additive height calculations, could make something shrink. (Unless its height is negative, as Stuart said.) A clear problem statement, maybe some sample in/out values, and concise/expository code help a ton!

Comment: @StuartGolodetz i'm sorry it was very quick typing my explanation is that the circles shrink really badly till it resembles only lines then move or just freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heights are growing geometrically to extremely large values. To see why, let your program tell you what's going on. Use println'ss or printf's to show you program state. For instance you could have a Shape-derived class like so:

```
public class MyShape extends Shape {
   private String name;
   private static int shapeCount = 1;

   public MyShape() {
      name = "Shape " + shapeCount;
      shapeCount++;
   }

   @Override
   public void display(Graphics page) {
      page.setColor(color);
      page.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
   }

   @Override
   public void move() {
      System.out.printf("%s: [x: %d, y: %d, w: %d, h: %d, mX: %d, my: %d]%n", 
            name, x, y, width, height, moveX, moveY);
      // Rebound X
      if (x <= 0 || x >= 400 - width) {
         moveX = moveX * -1;
      }

      // ... etc...
```